# Create Json deserializer to fix moved classes

Tags: c#, json, class, json-deserialization

I've recently started working on a codebase that was initially written with one class that contained all other classes, then that class was serialized and saved as JSON.

The issue now is that the project has grown and the file contains around 30 classes, but moving them breaks the deseralization because the original class path no longer works.

For example there is a class called "everything" and a class within "everything" called "class1", this is written to JSON as: "everything+class1" meaning that if we remove class1 from "everything" and into a Models folder the JSON doesn't deserialize as the class can't be found.

There are too many JSON files actively in use to just make the change as it would make all old json files unusable which I can't do so is there anyway to move the classes and make the deserializer smart enough to know the class has moved?

Comment: Could you give an example of the actual model class structure? I don’t really follow why changing/moving classes would break things if the model to/from which the serialization is being done is the same as previously. Or is this “moving” in relation to the model?

Comment: So basically the JSON files are used by a web client to render what's been created in a wpf editor app, everything is contained within one class with implicit class calling, for example a declaration for a dictionary would be dictionary<int, everything.exampleClass>, this means that when trying to deserialize the jsons it's specifically looking within everything for that class not the whole solution. It wouldn't be an issue for newly created jsons but all the old ones break

Comment: What serializer are you using currently?  JSON doesn't really have type information built into the standard, so how are type names represented in your JSON file?